# Run Python Console via docker-compose on Pycharm

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I'm having some problems running pycharm with a remote python interpreter via docker-compose. Everything works just great except Python console when I press the run button it just shows the following message:

> "Error: Unable to locate container name for service "web" from
>   docker-compose output"

I really can't understand why it keeps me showing that if my `docker-compose.yml` provides a `web` service.

Any help?

**EDIT:**

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  dados:
    driver: local
  media:
    driver: local
  static:
    driver: local

services:
  beat:
    build: Docker/beat
    depends_on: 
      - web
      - worker
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
  db:
    build: Docker/postgres
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - dados:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  jupyter:
    build: Docker/jupyter
    command: jupyter notebook
    depends_on: 
      - web
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
  python:
    build:
      context: Docker/python
      args:
        REQUIREMENTS_ENV: 'dev'
    image: helpdesk/python:3.6
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.6
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: always
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Docker/web/Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - python
      - db
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
  worker:
    build: Docker/worker
    depends_on: 
      - web
      - redis
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.6

# Set requirements environment
ARG REQUIREMENTS_ENV
ENV REQUIREMENTS_ENV ${REQUIREMENTS_ENV:-prod}

# Set PYTHONUNBUFFERED so the output is displayed in the Docker log
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        apt-transport-https

# Configure yarn repo
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Install APT dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        locales \
        openssl \
        yarn

# Set locale
RUN locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8 && \
    localedef -i pt_BR -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias pt_BR.UTF-8

ENV LANG pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL pt_BR.UTF-8

# Copy requirements files to the container
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/requirements
COPY requirements/requirements-common.txt \
    requirements/requirements-$REQUIREMENTS_ENV.txt \
    /tmp/requirements/

# Install requirements
RUN pip install \
    -i http://root:test@pypi.defensoria.to.gov.br:4040/root/pypi/+simple/ \
    --trusted-host pypi.defensoria.to.gov.br \
    -r /tmp/requirements/requirements-$REQUIREMENTS_ENV.txt

# Remove requirements temp folder
RUN rm -rf /tmp/requirements
```

This is the python image Dockerfile, the web Dockerfile just declares from this image and copies the source folder to the container.

Comment: nope... honestly I gave up months ago. I'm running a jupyter instance via docker to use a more resourceful shell on my project.

Comment: Issue was fixed but regressed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18668#tab=Comments

Comment: Might as well document this here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18748 Here is ticket, as of jul 19, its been fixed, just needs to be released. -- waiting game..

Comment: This is probably a long shot but have you tried setting the `container_name` property on the web service?

Comment: Any attempts at configuration in pycharm would be helpful here, as well as knowing whether this docker-compose setup works outside of pycharm.

Comment: @TyroneWilson I was thinking the same thing, since the default behaviour for docker-compose is to assign a random prefix to instances

Comment: See this:https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/03/docker-compose-getting-flask-up-and-running/

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is an dependency chain problem, `web` depends on `python` so, when the `python` container gets up, `web` one still not exists. That may cause the error.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Installing required libraries via command line and running the python interpreter from the PATH should suffice.

You can also refer to the JetBrains manual, as to how they have configured for the interpreters of their IDEs.